# cube partitions: is the fact table in the DSV designer just one of the cube partitions?

Tags: ssas, olap, fact-table

There are 16 partitions for a fact table. All 16 of them have the same structure and have the same aggregation scheme. 15 of them contains data and while the 16th contains no data.

So, is  the fact table in the DSV designer just one of those partitions? (the name in the header matches one of the partitions though)

if it is so, then whenver we need to process a different partition, just replace the fact table in the designer and reprocess?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

partitions can either be bound to a table in the DSV or they can be bound using "Query Binding" directly to a table in your data source. If you can't see the 16 tables in your DSV, they must have been bound directly using "Query Binding".

If you click on your partition in the "Partitions" tab then check the Source property in the properties window, it will tell you where a particular partition reads it's data from.

Comment: thanx darren...i knew there has to be something that binds all of 'em together but just dint knew how it does. The query binding is the one. Thanx